# how to append data to an executable and use it inside this application

Tags: c++

I want to build an C#/Wpf Packer.
I am using a C++ application which will start the packed/crypted C# application.

Currently I have to build this C++ app everytime I want to release my Main-App.
(C#/Wpf-App is included as external Array of Bytes)

Now I want to build a simple tool to do this work, but I dont want to build the "launcher" all the time!

So my idea is just to modify the launcher.

For that I need a way to modify this executable and I need to be able to use this modified data inside the launcher, like it would be compiled.

I dont want to reserve a static sized array inside the launcher, cause I dont know what could be the biggest data-size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to do that. Unfortunately none of them is straightforward nor standard except one: use a makefile that automatically builds the launcher. IMHO, unless you have special requirements such as building the launcher on a system with no development environment, it is probably the most simple and robust way.

As you explicitely ask for other solutions, I will give 2:

- on Windows, you could store the c# app as a resource. Once that's done, you can use a resource editor to change it *on the fly* or build a custom editor using the WinAPI functions `BeginUpdateResource`, `UpdateResource` and `EndUpdateResource`. You later load the resource with `LoadResource` in the launcher.
- you could make the laucher program know its real size and just seek behind that size and load what follows as the C# app. To build it, you just need to copy the actual C++ executable and *whatever you want it to process*. The hard part here is that there is no portable way to identify the size or the end of an executable at compile time. You could try a two pass build:

  - first pass, you set the size to an arbitrary value. You build and look at the real size
  - second pass, you set the size to what has been observed in first pass. As you only modify a size_t value, the size of the executable should not change. But I strongly urge you to control that size twice. Repeat if it is not the same (it could happen if the compiler was too clever and merged identical constants).

But as I already said, my choice would be to use a makefile to automatically generate the launcher each time the C# app is rebuilt

Comment: Thanks. Your are right, my initial wish/idea was to use this tool on ANY machine.. Thought about a "makefile + compiler" solution too, but dont want to deliver that compiler and all dependencies.. I will try your solutions and see whats the "best" way. :)

Comment: Do you know a tool or an easy way to convert a VS2015 c++ project into a working Makefile project?

Comment: I no longer use the full Visual Studio (only express versions) but if I correctly remember old Visual C++ projects could be converted to a makefile that could later be used with NMAKE.